# Override log4j.properties from within the log4j.properties

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

Is it possible to state something like - "override file = /log4j.properties"

From within the log4j.properties and to link to the actual log4j config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. However, you can configure the system property `log4j.configuration` specifying the path of a configuration file. Add the following parameter when you create the JVM:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=path/to/log4j-test.properties AwesomeApp
```